# Squid Logs NTLM usernames only for certain requests

Tags: proxy, authentication, squid, open-source, ntlm

Currently I have squid 3.2 setup with NTLM authentication and LDAP Group pulls. I also have MySar running to pull the reports.

It seems that the way the logging works is by passing them twice, one to authenticate and one to accept. However with things that are denied no username is logged, which makes squid hard to troubleshoot someones problem in the office considering we have terminal servers which has multiple users on 1 I.P address.

So I guess my question is, Are there any workarounds for this? Anyway to change the way it logs so we know if something was denied which user it was?

**My squid.conf**

```
#=======================
# NTLM AUTHENTICATION  > 
#=======================
auth_param ntlm program /usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp
auth_param ntlm children 10
auth_param ntlm keep_alive on
#auth_param ntlm max_challenge_lifetime_reuses 5

#===============================
# EXTERNAL ACL TO PULL GROUPS  >
#===============================
external_acl_type nt_group %LOGIN /usr/lib64/squid/ext_wbinfo_group_acl

#=======================
# ACL                  >
#=======================

#ACL for Groups
acl CustomerServiceGroup external nt_group CustomerService
acl InternetToolsGroup external nt_group InternetTools
acl AllCustomerInternetSitesGroup external nt_group AllCustomerInternetSites
acl UnrestrictedGroup external nt_group UnrestrictedInternet
acl WarehouseGroup external nt_group Warehouse

# Security Provisions
#acl manager proto cache_object
#acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
#acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

#The Network
acl Thenetwork src 10.10.0.0/16
acl ntlm proxy_auth REQUIRED

# ANTI-PROXY GROUP
acl ProxyBL dstdomain "/etc/squid/global/BL-proxy.txt"
# WHITELIST GROUPS
acl CallCenterWL dstdomain "/etc/squid/callcenter/WL-callcenter.txt"
#acl WarehouseWL dstdomain "/etc/squid/warehouse/WL-warehouse.txt"

# BLACKLIST GROUPS
#acl CallCenterBL dstdomain "/etc/squid/callcenter/BL-callcenter.txt"

# Keywords Whitelist
#acl CallCenterKW url_regex -i "/etc/squid/callcenter/KW-callcenter.txt"

# Keywords Blacklist
acl GlobalKW url_regex -i "/etc/squid/global/KW-global.txt"

# Ports
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http

acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#===================
# ACL RULES        >
#===================
# Global Blacklist
#http_access deny Blacklist all


# Global Deny Blacklist and Keyword filters
http_access deny GlobalKW all
http_access deny ProxyBL all

# Unrestricted Group allow all
http_access allow all UnrestrictedGroup ntlm

# Enabled Whitelist & Keywords
#http_access allow CallCenterKW InternetToolsGroup ntlm

# Activates Whitelist
http_access allow CallCenterWL CustomerServiceGroup ntlm
http_access allow CallCenterWL InternetToolsGroup ntlm
http_access allow CallCenterWL AllCustomerInternetSitesGroup ntlm


# WarehouseGroup Restriction
http_access deny all WarehouseGroup

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
#http_access allow manager localhost
#http_access deny manager

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# TheNetwork allow with auth * Allows everything, only enable when needed * 
#http_access allow Thenetwork ntlm

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
#http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

#=====================
# ACL ACCESS RULES   >
#=====================
# Allow any keywords
#http_access allow CallCenterKW ntlm

# Allow only the whitelist
#http_access allow CallCenterWL ntlm 

# Deny anything not on the whitelist  
#http_access deny !CallCenterWL 

# Deny everything else
http_access deny all

#================
# CONFIG MISC   >
#================


#Cache administrator Email
cache_mgr xxx@xxx.com


# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 8080

# We recommend you to use at least the following line.
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256
#useragent_log /var/log/squid/user.log

#access_log /var/log/squid/naccess.log squid

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

#debug_options ALL,9
```

**My access.log**

```
1362426657.752      0 10.10.7.71 TCP_DENIED/403 3956 
GET http://www.porn.com/ -                        HIER_NONE/- text/html
1362426722.483    154 10.10.7.71 TCP_MISS/200 1841
GET                 http://media.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/css/global.css 
alucas HIER_DIRECT/24.143.206.89  text/css
```

Notice how the denied website returned no user, however one that was accepted did log a username.

I'm sure this is just something I am missing, or doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Aaron